# Recessed lighting flickers when ceiling fan turns off

Tags: electrical

my home is going through a reno and in my living room I had a ceiling fan/light combo that was wired to separate switches. We had an electrician add recessed lighting to the room and had those connected to the switch that had controlled the ceiling fan light. I then replaced the fan with one that did not have a light fixture kit (not really needed now), but i wired it up exactly as the old fan had been wired. Fan works, recessed lights work but if the recessed lights are on when I switch the fan off the lights briefly flicker. I'm assuming this has something to do with my wiring of the fan, and not with what the electrician did for the recessed lighting, but electrical is not really my strong suit. Any insight that you have would be appreciated - aside from being a nuisance, I want to make sure the flicker isn't a potential hazard. Here's the wiring as it it currently, and thanks in advance:

- Two whites from ceiling to one white from fan
- One black from ceiling to one black from fan
- One black from ceiling to one blue to fan
- Bare wire from ceiling to all grounds from fan (and mount)

Comment: Flickering lights are likely due to loose connections. Turn the power off then double check that all wires are tightly screwed down at the switches and that the wire nuts are tightly turned at the lights and at the fan - I'd start with those at your fan since that was A) the last thing installed (and seems to have been the trigger for the issue), and B) it was a DIY install vs a pro install - yes, pros make mistakes, too, but us DIYers are more likely to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the assumption that your new recessed lighting is LED.  Going on that assumption, LEDs are very sensitive to voltage variations. LEDs vary in quality as well, some are more tolerant, others less so.  On incandescent lamps, a quick drop/recovery  in voltage wouldn't be noticeable bc you have a filament that would have to cool down a bit and then heat up again.  That takes time. LEDs respond instantly. So you might have a small voltage spike when you turn off your ceiling fan that the lights are reacting to.

Very unlikely this is a safety issue.   If it's really bugging you, you might have to run the lights on a separate circuit (if practical) to minimize the problem.